# Pandas: Subtracting columns based on row values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently working with data from a camera that tracks the location of a robotic agent and humans moving around it. I want to set the distance of the people relative to the robot rather than the grid the camera is currently using. Below is an example of the formatted data:

```
         x  idx          time  type
0  -24.782    7  1.390789e+09     0    
1   25.832    6  1.390789e+09     0
2   47.513    5  1.390789e+09     0    
3   42.492    4  1.390789e+09     0    
4   10.387    3  1.390789e+09     0    
5  -12.468    2  1.390789e+09     0    
6   44.725    1  1.390789e+09     0    
7  -13.452    0  1.390789e+09     1
```

`Type = 1` indicates that the agent identified is the robot and I'd like to subtract all the 'x' values where `Type == 0` (humans)  by the robot's (`Type == 1`) position(only when the time value is the same).

I've made some ham-handed attempts at doing this, but short of iterating through and then rebuilding the data frame, I have been unable to do it efficiently. Is there a more pythonic way to go about this?

Comment: Where's the code sir?

Comment: Is there only ever one `type=1` for the same time?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: Yes, there is only one type =1

Comment: @FelixLabelle is what? What?

Comment: 0    -11.330
1     39.284
2     60.965
3     55.944
4     23.839
5      0.984
6     58.177

Comment: I'm not sure how to correctly format the array, but those are the expected answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split by type, merge on time, then subtract:

```
merged_df = df[df['type'] == 0].merge(df[df['type'] == 1], on='time')
merged_df['diff'] = merged_df['x_x'] - merged_df['x_y']
```

Comment: Works well and is very elegant, thank you! I'd upvote your answer but I don't have the reputation for it